# printing a pretty table in c in a linux-terminal

Tags: c, printf

I have written a small database for students. After getting the data from Terminal,  I want to print this data in a pretty table. This Table looks like:

```
lastname|firstname|enrollement nr|subject|nationality.
```

But I am not able to print a whole line of data. It means if I want to print informations about one student, the data will be split into two lines. The header of the table will be not split but each line of the table will be split. Here is the code:

```
 void display_db(){
    printf("lastname|firstname|enrollement nr|subject   |nationality\n");
    printf("========================================================\n");
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
         printf("%10s|%10s|%10d|%10s|%10s\n",           
             (db+i)->lastname,(db+i)->firstname,(db+i)->mNr,   (db+i)->subject, (db+i)->nationality);
    }
 }
```

Here a picture:

[image]

After deleting the special character '\n', I modified the code for printing the table. The table is now pretty. Here is the code:

```
void display_db(){
printf("%10s|%10s|%10s|%30s|%10s\n","lastname","firstname","enroll. nr","subject","nationality");
printf("========================================================\n");
int i;
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
printf("%10s|%10s|%10d|%30s|%10s\n",            
        (db+i)->lastname,(db+i)->firstname,(db+i)->mNr, (db+i)->subject, (db+i)->nationality);
}
```

}

Comment: Aparently the string in `(db+i)->subject` is terminated with a newline symbol.

Comment: I wonder about the `|` separating the subject and nationality. Ah! Too much cropping

Comment: Only the `subject` header is 10 characters long, the ret is either shorter or longer. No wonder nothing aligns with a repeated `%10s` for all data items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the trailing newline from the struct element(s)

```
size_t element_len = strlen(element);
if (element_len && (element[element_len - 1] == '\n')) {
    element[--element_len] = 0; // remove trailing newline and update element_len
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working. The problem is that fgets is saving the character '\n'. So I delete this special character. Thank you